# Is it possible to display progress of Asynchronous IO

Tags: c, asynchronous, io, posix

I am trying to implement file copy program with POSIX Asynchronous IO APIs in linux.

I tried this:

```
main() {
    char data[200];
    int fd = open("data.txt", O_RDONLY); // text file on the disk
    struct aiocb aio;

    aio.aio_fildes = fd;
    aio.aio_buf = data;
    aio.aio_nbytes = sizeof(data);
    aio.aio_offset = 0;

    memset(&aio, 0, sizeof(struct aiocb));
    aio_read(arg->aio_p);
    int counter = 0;
    while (aio_error(arg->aio_p) == EINPROGRESS) {
          printf("counter: %d\n", counter++);
    }

    int ret = aio_return(&aio);
    printf("ret value %d \n",ret);

    return 0;
}
```

But counter giving different results every time when I run

Is it possible to display progress of aio_read and aio_write functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"?  Please specific about what went wrong.

Comment: Basic debugging techniques suggest capturing and printing the vale returned by `aio_error()` so you know why your loop terminates.  It presumably does not return EINPROGRESS, but what does it return?  Maybe the I/O is complete?

Comment: I used EINPROGRESS because I am trying to learn progress. If I/O is complete, obviously progress is %100 :) But this code returns different results every time when I run. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: You didn’t check the call to `aio_read()` and you don’t show how you initialize the structure, so you don’t know whether your request is valid, and we have no way of knowing either.  Sometimes you can cut corners on error checking when the code is working, but as soon as things go wrong, you need the checking.  You need to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added MCVE but this is not related about my implementation. My question is related about POSIX Asynchronous IO APIs. Is there any way to get current cursor position or any different solution for displaying progress?

Comment: You’re still not checking and saving and printing the results of the system calls.  If the file is a disk file, the write will complete immediately.  There’ll be no time for it to be “in progress”.  To get some sort of “in progress” indication, you’d need to do something like write to a pipe or FIFO and have nothing actively reading (but able to read) and send enough data (64 KiB?) to fill the buffer so the AIO is forced to wait to complete.  To avoid deadlock, the non-reading reader needs to be a separate process, probably; a separate thread might also work.

Comment: If you want to know the progress, then use a separate thread to handle the reads/writes in a nonblocking fashion; you only need one thread for any number of open descriptors. I'm baffled as to why you would even want to try to shoehorn POSIX AIO into a synchronous use case (and your use case *is* synchronous by definition, because you *are* interested in its progress, and not just its completion/error status).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different results because each different execution has its own context of execution that may differe from others (Do you always follow the exact same path to go from your house to the bank? Even if yes, elapsed time to reach the bank always exactly the same? Same task at the end - you're in the bank, different executions). What your program tries to measure is not I/O completion but the number of time it tests for completion of some async-I/O.

And no, there is no concept of percentage of completion of a given async-I/O.